# Abrir link apenas com .com - Android WebView

Tags: android, webview

No código abaixo, *link* com *mcpack* são a abertos no *WebView* do aplicativo, porém, às vezes, ele abre no navegador padrão, o que eu faço?

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, final String url)
{
    if (url.contains("https://www.mediafire.com/file/") || (url.endsWith("mcpack") || (url.contains("https://www.mediafire.com/download_repair.php") || (url.contains("http://engine.addroplet.com/")) ))) { // Could be cleverer and use a regex
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);

        return false;



    }

    mWebView.stopLoading();
    mWebView.goBack();
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Textures.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Navegador");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Deseja abrir o navegador?");
    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


    alertDialog.show();




    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na documentação `Android` do methodo [shouldOverrideUrlLoad](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) diz:

> Do not call `WebView.loadUrl(String)` with the request's URL and then `return true`. This unnecessarily cancels the current load and starts a new load with the same URL. The **correct way** to continue loading a given URL is to simply `return false`, **without** calling `WebView.loadUrl(String)`.

Que resumindo quer dizer: **não** chame o `WebView.loadUrl` isso fará com que outra requisição comece, apenas retorne `false`.

Pode ser isso que esteja fazendo seu código funcionar de forma instável. Você pode tirar o `mWebView.loadUrl(url);` e só retornar false ou colocar como o código abaixo.

Lembrando que se você retornar `true` ele vai abortar a requisição.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, final String url)
{
    if (url.contains("https://www.mediafire.com/file/") || (url.endsWith("mcpack") || (url.contains("https://www.mediafire.com/download_repair.php") || (url.contains("http://engine.addroplet.com/")) ))) { // Could be cleverer and use a regex
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)
    }
}
```

Outro detalhe é que você fala *"link com mcpack"* sendo que no código você só esta verificando se ele termina com `url.endsWith("mcpack")`. Então também vale apena você colocar alguns `Log.d` no seu código para verificar se realmente esta entrando neste `if`.

Comment: Não resolveu, continua abrindo no navegador :-(

Comment: @Daniel Vale apena você colocar alguns `Log.d` no seu código para verificar se realmente esta entrando neste metodo e nesse `if`. Algo como `Log.d("TESTE-WEBVIEW", "ENTROU NO METODO "+url )` logo no inicio da função e outro dentro do `if` `Log.d("TESTE-WEBVIEW", "ENTROU NO IF"+url )` e ver se aparece no `Logcat`

Comment: Tentei duas vezes, na primeira não fez o download, e na segunda pediu para abrir o navegador. ENTROU NO METODO https://www.mediafire.com/file/2t8pfp3o8eo9tm3/Dark_Mode_v1.8.0_r-2.mcpack/file
TESTE-WEBVIEW                                ENTROU NO METODO http://download1638.mediafire.com/x1549vkcyldg/2t8pfp3o8eo9tm3/Dark+Mode+v1.8.0+r-2.mcpack
TESTE-WEBVIEW                                ENTROU NO METODO https://www.mediafire.com/file/2t8pfp3o8eo9tm3/Dark_Mode_v1.8.0_r-2.mcpack/file

Comment: o `if` não vai funcionar pq não termina com `mcpack`, você vai ter que usar `contains` ao invés de `endsWith`

Comment: Realmente não, porém quando o usuário clicar em download abrirá outro link, nele o final contém mcpack.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funciona!